# How to force CloudFront CName to handle non-www requests?

Tags: amazon-s3, dns, amazon-cloudfront, cname, namecheap

I'm new to CloudFront and was wondering how to force it to redirect. In Apache it's just through Virtual Host, but with CloudFront, I'm confused how to do it.

Here is my scenario

NameCheap

`CNAME` | `www` | `random12345.cloudfront.net` (where my site files are)

---

AWS

ACM - requirement for CloudFront for custom SSL (N.Virginia)

Domain Name: `sample.com`

Additional Domain Name(s): `*.sample.com`

---

CloudFront Distribution

Domain Name: `random12345.cloudfront.net`

CName: `sample.com`
`*.sample.com`

---

Result

WORKED: `https://www.sample.com` | `www.sample.com`

NOT WORKING: `sample.com` | `https://sample.com` | `http://sample.com`

Typing these in the search bar results to `Error: This site can’t be reached sample.com’s server IP address could not be found. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

I attempted to create an S3 bucket to force redirect to `https://www.sample.com`
but can't create since CNAME `www.sample.com` is already used for the CloudFront Distribution. Can't use `@` in `CNAME` since it is not recommended on root configuration due to its effect on MX records

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Based on `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`, if yo go to (for example) https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/ and put your domain name there (without https:// and www), I suspect that it will not resolve to any ip address?

Comment: Added answer @Woppi this is already implement answer if any question add in comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to following step for redirecting non-www domain to www :

**Note**: `www.example.com` bucket should have code and `example.com` will be empty bucket only configuration mention below.

1. Create `example.com` S3 bucket.
2. Go to S3 bucket properties -> Static website hosting then select Redirect request add value as `www.example.com`
   [image: Redirect S3 request]
3. Set Bucket policy and CORS same `www.example.com` bucket
4. Create CloudFront for `example.com` use origin as `example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` not which selection dropdown giving.
5. Select user *.example.com ACM for https
6. Then create Route53 Entry for this `example.com` as A record select respective CloudFront origin for `example.com`.

This domain is transferred to AWS if you don't want full NS record then only move A record to AWS.
Then you are done.

Comment: Did you also use Route 53 as DNS, or retain it to something like NameCheap / GoDaddy? Did you have a CNAME for the CloudFront? Also when you create this, at which point does it point to your actual project... is it the CNAME in namecheap pointed to the cloudfront of actual project? Because on Step 6, you selected Step 4 cloudfront distribution. Thanks but I'm still confused as when I tried this I'm running into can't create distribution for s3 bucket since CNAME is already assigned to the cloudfront (actual project).

Comment: You have to move to actual project to `www.example.com` and keep `example.com` empty because this is doing only redirection.